# VBA excel 64 - webbrowser control crashes when open a pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, 64-bit, web-controls

I have a VBA excel form with a webcontrol that I use for displaying a pdf. It works fine on 32 but crashes on 64. ( no error, just crashes). I tried:

- tested on different machines with 64 Office - it crashes
- I tested various options and it seems like it helps if I show the form before I load the pdf but only once, if I want change the pdf again after that it crashes.

The code I use to update the pdf is:

`invoice_review.WebBrowser.Navigate (invoice_path)`

Also tried the following but still having the same problem:

```
invoice_review.WebBrowser.Document.write "<HTML><Body>x<embed src=""" & invoice_path & """ width=""100%"" height=""100%"" /></Body></HTML>"
```

In event viewer I get this error

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.14931.20806, time stamp: 0x635d4918
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.22000.918, time stamp: 0x57b668f2
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00000000000935cf
Faulting process id: 0x5d58
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8fd4c8af0801a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 03ea2603-9af6-4f74-99a5-ca09598936c6
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I couldn’t find any good way to display the pdf inside a VBA from, the adobe controller is not working properly. Do you have any idea what is wrong or what other option I have for this?

Comment: NT Status 0xC0000409 (-1073740791)

Windows Error 0x502 (1282)
NT Status Message:

The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be opened in a Userform? Why not just open it using whatever the user has set to their default viewer?

Comment: Hi Brax, 
Initially that was my solution. However, this is for invoice review, it’s much cleaner to have everything in one place. It will be a lot easier for the user if they could have on screen for review. (sample of screen here:  https://ibb.co/L1zC8XR)

Comment: The take away is - 1. Your code causes the error or 2. Excel or Internet Explorer or Adobe causes the error. Today while the web browser is available it doesn't quite work right. You can look up the function in NTDLL by loading it in a debugger and looking at the offset in the error message. But perhaps you should do system troubleshooting - does your code run on another computer - If not does it run on a clean install of Windows?

Comment: Hi Lundt, 
The code runs locally, and it crashes only on the Excel 64 version. I tested on 6 different machines for 64 – all crashed excel and 5 machines on 32 – is working well. 
I don’t think is my code, as I said VBA doesn’t throw any error, and always crashes at this code: invoice_review.WebBrowser.Navigate (invoice_path).
I think it could be Adobe or IE as you said, but I was hopping that someone else might know how to overcome this. 
I'll try with a debugger.

Comment: See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/brief-introduction-to-windows-debugger.html om how to load symbols. Then do `ns` at that offset + Base Address of the dll.

Comment: PS Parameters passed in brackets are passed `ByVal` the default, which you are intentionally overriding, is `ByRef`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if Adobe is installed as add in with IE11 on the not working machine. If somebody can tell me how i can download and install Adobe for IE11 on windows 10, i like to know.

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a comment. Please do not add comments as answers, and if you have a question, feel free to create your own instead of asking it in someone else's question.